# Gamma functions and their arguments

Tags: gamma-function

I have a problem where I am trying to get a function suc as $\exp(i \arg(\Gamma(x)))$ is it true to say that it is equal to $\Gamma(x)^{i}$ otherwise how else can one find such an exponential relationship?

Comment: This has little or nothing to do with the gamma function. What you need to know is: $w^a=e^{a\ln w}$ (different branches of the log might yield different answers), and $\ln w=\ln|w|+i\arg w$ (the different choices for $\arg w$ yield the different branches of $\ln w$).